# How to print an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating an array but when I print it in console appear as empty but inside has objects.

```
var UTResults = [];
function(x){
    UTResults.push(x.description);
}
console.log(UTResults);
```

*Results*

[image]

How to to print just 1 object?

Comment: Is that an anonymous function? Why don't you just access the array

Comment: where are you calling this function?

Comment: `function(x){` this part is wrong unless it is a function expression

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(UTResults));` log at `console`?

Comment: @guest271314 I got only "[]" as a string

Comment: This usually happens when you console.log it before it has anything in it, but when you actually click on it, the console has the references, so that is why you see the actual data. Perhaps you can call console.log after you are sure the array is populated. try this setTimeout(function() { console.log(UTResults)}, 2000); -- just to show that your array actually does have the data.

Comment: Try inside function following `.push()` call

Comment: @jamesemanon thanks, the time was the fact, I try setTimeout and it works. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the log is printed to the console, it is empty but it has a reference to the array. So when the array is altered by adding things to it after it will reflect this but not until you open the array in the console as you have done. Make sure that the array is populated before the log is executed and it should be displayed "correctly".